# using environment variables from AWS in a nodeJS project

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

I have created a pipeline on AWS to deploy a nodeJS project from source (codecommit). I use codebuild to build the project and codedeploy to deploy it. Everything works but I need environment variables in my nodejs code.

I have the following code:

```
console.log(process.env.CUSTOM_VARIABLE);
```

when I add "CUSTOM_VARIABLE" as an environment variable to the codebuild project, it doesn't work.

I found this link: https://blog.shikisoft.com/define-environment-vars-aws-codebuild-buildspec/

I'm guessing in my nodeJS-code, I don't need "process.env" but I need to access the environment variable another way. Does someone knows how?

**Partial solution (for now):**

I have ec2 instances (dev and staging). I set the environment variable directly on the server with `export ENVIRONMENT=dev`. This works.

Comment: So this is code running on CodeBuild?

Comment: yes. In my nodejs project i have ``process.env.CUSTOM_VARIABLE``. When building the code, I want to replace this wat a value. So when deploying the code, the nodejs function works (the env variable is an url for axios).

Comment: Are you talking about having the environment variable available during the codebuild run or the actual run of the built software? Codebuild cannot set environment variables for other systems, what is the result of codebuild buidling your project and where do you then run that deployable code? E.g. on Lambda?

Comment: Is your CUSTOM_VARIABLE a secret or more a config like value?

Comment: it is an environment variable I need when running the code (nodeJS). When starting the server, I need to pass an URL as an environment variable. I want this url to be different based on the pipeline I use (eg different deployment).

Comment: What is the compute type for your deploy stage?

Comment: the compute type is EC2